# Troubleshoot Android File Variable in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

If, in Eclipse, I use:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

and want to test that it is resolving correctly, how do I do that?

```
If I write: Log.d("Path = ", path);
```

it complains that path is not a string. Is there something like println, echo, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are calling takes two strings for its parameters, so instead you would call:

```
Log.d("Path=", path.toString());
```

If you want the path of the file you can use the getPath() method instead of toString().

Answer (score 0):

You can check using below snippet or handle file object for more values. In your example path is File object.

```
if(path.isDirectory()) {
       Log.d(..
    }
```